# Sending information to a textbox from a class to a form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, instances

I asked a question a couple of days ago about populating a listbox on a form from a class. It works and was great! However I now want to do the same with a textbox or a label. The answer from that question is below:

> What you are doing is creating a new instance of the form - I presume
>   you are trying to add items in a listbox on an existing form?
>
> If so do this.
>
> Create a function on the form with the listbox like:
>
> ```
>     public void addItemToListBox(string item)
>     {
>          listBox1.Items.Add(item);
>     }
> ```
>
> Then, in the class (remember to add the using System.Windows.Forms
>   reference)
>
> ```
>    public void doStuff()
>     {
>  //Change Form1 to whatever your form is called
>  foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
>  {
>       if (frm.GetType() == typeof(Form1))
>       {
>            Form1 frmTemp = (Form1)frm;
>            frmTemp.addItemToListBox("blah");
>
>       }
>  }
>     }
> ```

This works well. Now I want to do the same with a textbox. I was wondering if someone could explain or if someone has a link on this?

I have a form and a class. The form makes a new instance of the class and initiates a method in the class, say a maths equation 4+4; I want the answer, "8" to then be shown in a textbox or label on form1, from the method in the class.

Comment: That answer is pretty bad; it's just terrible design from the start...

Comment: are you want to set text to a TextBox from your class?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186046/add-item-to-list-in-a-class-in-c-sharp/13186131#13186131

Comment: @DmitryMartovoi That answer is better than this one, but still not as good as it really should be.  In that particular case the parent form should subscribe to an event on the child form; the child shouldn't have a reference to the parent.  That said, we don't know if the "other class" is even a child form or not.

Comment: yes, i know, but its was simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing, with your edit, is a model in which your `Form` *uses* another class.  The class that is being used should have no knowledge of the `Form`, it's controls, or how the result of its calculation could possibly be used.

Your other class shouldn't find the form, it shouldn't call any methods or fields of the form, or anything.  What it should do is just return a value:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    public int Add(int first, int second)
    {
        return first + second;
    }
}
```

Then the form can do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //create an instance of the other class
    OtherClass other = new OtherClass();
    //call it's add method, and then use the result to set the textbox's text
    textbox1.Text = other.Add(4, 4).ToString(); 
}
```

The other class should be responsible for doing the calculations, creating a result, but not updating the user interface based on those results.  All of the user interface logic should be contained in the `Form` class.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in Form1.cs:

```
public void SetText(string text)
{
    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

And in the class file:

```
frmTemp.SetText("XYZ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looping through all open forms seems like a ... novel ... way to get the form in question.

Instead, you should keep a reference to the form until you finally close it, and access variables on the form (like list boxes and text boxes) directly through that.

So, where you create the form, do something like

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
```

// Open the dialog or whatever you are going to do with form1

// When you need to access a text control:

```
form1.textBox1.Text = "Some value"; // Assumes the control is called textBox1
```

If *doStuff* is happening from a model (a class that models some aspect of real-world behavior), you are following a poor design pattern.

Models should have no idea of how they are presented.  Instead, in a typical WinForms application, a parent form would likely hold the variable *form1*.  In newer types of UI projects, you would see a MVC or MVVM pattern to separate the Model, the View (presentation/forms) and Controller (flow control).  One can also follow an MVC pattern with WinForms, though many/most WinForms applications I have seen don't do that.

Comment: Making the controls, such as textboxes, public for a form is also generally considered bad design.  Not quite as bad as using openforms, but still bad.  Also note that it may or may not be appropriate for this other class to have a reference to the form at all.  (We don't know enough to answer that.)  It's possible that the other class should subscribe to an event, the form should subscribe to an event, that the other class should return a value to the form, or one of several other possible options.

Comment: @Servy: I added to my answer probably after your comment.  I agree because that leads to spaghetti code, but just providing a function wrapper to get/set doesn't solve the design issue but rather just adds a layer of the same bad design pattern.  The right way is with MVC, with accessability restricted so that each part of the pattern only can access what it needs to get the job done.

Comment: Yep, I agree with what you added in your edit.  So far I'm mostly just holding myself to saying what shouldn't be done in the various proposed solutions as the OP hasn't given enough information/context for provide what I would consider an appropriate solution.  If/when he does, I'll add an answer.  Needless to say it wouldn't involve get/set methods on the form any more than it would publicly expose internal controls.

Comment: Just pinging you.  The OP edited the question to explain his actual use case, so I have [now written an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13297383/1159478).

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you are using Visual Studio, you can specify the visiblity of each member, e.g. `private` or `public`. `private` is the default (if i remember correctly).</s>

If you change this to `public`, then you could do the following:

```
public void doStuff()
{
 //Change Form1 to whatever your form is called
 foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
 {
  if (frm is Form1)
  {
       var frmTemp = (Form1)frm;
       frmTemp.listBox1.Items.Add("blah");
       frmTemp.textBox1.Text += "hello world";
  }
 }
}
```

**Edit 1**
A better approach, would be to tell Form1 that it needs to update something, how it presents the data is of no concern to the class which is invoking the method.

```
private Form1 _FindForm()
{
   //assuming you can use Linq
   return Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();
}

public void displaySomething()
{
   var form = _FindForm();
   form.displaySomething();
}
```

---

```
public class Form1
{
  public void displaySomething()
  {
    //add an item to the list box
    listBox1.Items.Add("foo");

    //and change the text somewhere
    textBox1.Text += "bar";
  }
}
```

Form1 is now responsible for changing the controls it holds, rather than other - possibly - unrelated class manipulating them.
This keeps all of the UI logic `encapsulated` into Form1, and all the business logic can be held elsewhere.

Comment: This is taking a very poorly designed method and making it even worse...

Comment: 'Generate Member' is what i was thinking of, and by default its set to true, so members of a form are accessible publicly by default.

Comment: @Servy - yes this is not the best design, however it does answer the question of how to set text into a text box from outside of the Form.

Comment: When you see someone having trouble using a poorly designed method you should help them come up with a properly designed approach that solves the problem in a sustainable, maintainable, and effective manor so that they can propagate good techniques rather than bad ones.  This is especially true of someone just learning about a particular paradigm and is likely to emulate any examples he's given.  Setting all members of all of your forms to public by default is a **terrible** idea. You shouldn't expose your controls externally as a general rule, and be *very* wary of any solution suggesting it.

Comment: @Servy - hopefully the above edit shows a better example of how this could be achieved

Comment: @Servy, exposing the members was a 'means to an end' suggestion rather than a suggestion of good practice, i see your point - duly noted.

Comment: Your edit is only marginally better; it's still pretty bad.  Through much of the winform programming I see I see lots of people doing "whatever" as a means to an end.  It's just not sustainable, it doesn't scale, and it inhibits real understanding.  See my answer to this question for the appropriate way of solving this problem, based on the OP's edit.